# fish shell suggestions messing up integrated terminal in vs code

Tags: shell, visual-studio-code, fish

I have fish shell installed with Cygwin on windows 10. to use `fish` shell as an integrated terminal in vs code I added following settings

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe",
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["/bin/xhere", "/bin/fish"]
```

but, whenever I try to type in my terminal in vs code fish shell suggestions shows up next line

[image]

Comment: What fish version? What is `TERM` set to and is it appropriate for the the VS code terminal emulator?

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you call `fish` directly?  i.e. `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Cygwin64\\bin\\fish.exe"`

Comment: @MikePatrick sorry for late reply. yes, the problem persists even if I add above settings. i also tried
<code>
 "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["/bin/xhere", "/bin/fish"] </code>   
to start bash and then  manually start fish by typing command "fish"
 but that doesn't solve problem

Answer (score 1):

since this method changing shell is deprecated and the recommended way is to use profiles, here's what to add in vsc settings

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "Fish": {
    "path": "C:\\Cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe",
    "args": ["-lic","fish"]
    }
},
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Fish"
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** - changing the `omf theme` fixed the issue for me.

Earlier today I ran into a similar issue today as what you described.  Using the `fish` shell in VSCode as the integrated terminal while running Cygwin on Windows 10, and every keystroke seems to also trigger a new line.

I see by your screenshot that you are using the [oh-my-fish](https://github.com/oh-my-fish/oh-my-fish) package manager, with what appears to be the `default` theme.  I am also running `omf`, and I had the issue while the theme was set to `default`.  Switching to another theme resolved the issue and the characters stayed on one line as normal.  In my case I switched to the `cyan` theme - it seems to cooperate with VSCode just fine.

I'm going to guess that there are a few other `omf` themes that will have similar issues to this.  My experience of the `fish` shell has been that it's generally great, but I've come across several themes that do not work out-of-the-box on Cygwin (`dangerous` is another that comes to mind).  I am not sure why the `default` theme is not working in VSCode, it seems to do just fine in Cygwin in my experience.